# Why the `Omega' tactic can't solve a simple problem like this

Tags: coq

I have two theorems tst4 and tst3, why `omega' can solve tst4 but not tst3? This just does not make sense to me.

```
   Theorem tst4 : forall (a b c : nat), 
    (a = b + 1 /\ b = 0) -> (False \/ a >= 1).
    Proof. 
    intros.
    omega.
    Qed.

    Theorem tst3 : forall (a b c : nat), 
    (a = b + 1 /\ b = 0) -> (False \/ (a >= 1 /\ True)).
    Proof. 
    intros.
    omega.
    Qed.
```

Comment: On recent Coq versions one should use `lia` instead, because `omega` is deprecated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`omega` (or `lia` which—as pointed by @Anton Trunov—you should use instead) operates on integers and tries to prove properties about them or deduce falsehood from a contradiction in them. Hence it is able to deal with `False` in your goal.
`True` however has nothing to do with that. `omega` shouldn't be thought as an all-purpose tactic, it's really to deal with natural numbers or integers.

Actually `lia` is able to solve your goal, but I wouldn't rely on either to deal with stuff that doesn't have anything to do with numbers.
In your case, and assuming you stick with `omega` (or make the switch to `lia` and end up with another similar goal it can't solve) you can combine it with another tactic like the tactical `intuition`:

```
Theorem tst3 : 
  forall (a b c : nat), 
    (a = b + 1 /\ b = 0) -> 
    (False \/ (a >= 1 /\ True)).
Proof. 
  intros.
  intuition omega.
Qed.
```